# replace y with x using gsub() in R

Tags: r, gsub

My problem is that I want to replace y with x using gsub(), but not for all observations, I want to replace observations in y only with the following observations in x: keyword1 and keyword2.

My cols do not contain NA or missing values.

What I have

```
x =c('this', 'is', 'some', 'keyword1', 'or', 'terms', 'keyword2')
y =c('SFP', 'VERB', 'ADP', 'NOUN', 'ADP', 'VERB', 'SFP')
toString(y)
toString(x)
df = cbind(x,y)
df = data.frame(df)
df
         x    y
1     this  SFP
2       is VERB
3     some  ADP
4 keyword1 NOUN
5       or  ADP
6    terms VERB
7 keyword2  SFP
```

What I need:

```
      x    y
1     this SFP
2       is VERB
3     some ADP
4 keyword1 keyword1
5       or ADP
6    terms VERB
7 keyword2 keyword2
```

Comment: This is not a duplicate question, my cols do not contain NA or missing values.

Comment: Hint:  Character columns will make this easier and `grepl` is your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `gsub` as you don't want to replace the matched character itself. The following code will replace `y` elements with the keywords where `grepl` finds a match in column `x`.

```
keywords <- c("keyword1", "keyword2")
for (kw in keywords)
  df$y[grepl(kw, df$x)] <- kw
```

If you know that the matches will be exact, it is more natural to use:

```
for (kw in keywords)
      df$y[df$x == kw] <- kw.
```

---

FYI, you can create the dataframe more easily:

```
x = c('this', 'is', 'some', 'keyword1', 'or', 'terms', 'keyword2')
y = c('SFP', 'VERB', 'ADP', 'NOUN', 'ADP', 'VERB', 'SFP')
df = data.frame(x, y, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Rich Scriven suggested, let's first have character columns:

```
df <- data.frame(x, y, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Then a couple of nice options would be

```
z <- c("keyword1", "keyword2")
df$y[df$x %in% z] <- df$x[df$x %in% z]
# and
df$y <- ifelse(df$x %in% z, df$x, df$y)
```

`gsub` is not necessary here as your matches seem to be exact. That is, you are not looking for you keywords somewhere in a certain element of `df$y`.